# Unir tres tablas usando INNER JOIN y totalizar campos usando SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo tres tablas: productos, ingresos (de productos) y ventas.

¿Qué necesito?

Que en una misma tabla me muestre código del producto, total de  stock ingresado y total vendido.

Hecha la consulta, las sumas no me devuelven los valores correctos, sino un número muy superior a lo que en realidad ingresó o se vendió.

```
SELECT productos.codigo, SUM(ingresos.stock_ingresado), SUM(ventas.stock_vendido)
       FROM productos
       INNER JOIN ingresos ON productos.codigo=ingresos.codigo
       INNER JOIN ventas ON productos.codigo=ventas.codigo
GROUP BY productos.codigo;
```

Comment: Pásanos algún dato de muestra de ambas tablas y qué resultado esperarías para esos datos de prueba.

Answer (score 0):

Con la consulta que estás mostrando, lo que obtienes es la suma de stock ingresado o vendido para todos los productos agrupados por código, no la cantidad que tienes de producto en la base de datos. Fíjate en las cláusulas `GROUP BY` y las funciones `SUM`.

Si lo que quieres es saber las cantidades por producto (no la suma de ellas), debes omitir el `GROUP BY` (y por tanto, las funciones `SUM`):

```
SELECT productos.codigo, ingresos.stock_ingresado, ventas.stock_vendido
       FROM productos
       INNER JOIN ingresos ON productos.codigo=ingresos.codigo
       INNER JOIN ventas ON productos.codigo=ventas.codigo;
```

Comment: ¿Y en qué te basas para llegar a esa conclusión? :)

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es más fácil de observar cuando eliminas las funciones de agregado y ves como se duplican tus datos puesto que tienes múltiples filas por producto en las tablas de ingresos y ventas. Dejo un ejemplo de como se ve con datos de prueba.

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
    codigo  int)
INSERT INTO productos VALUES(1)

CREATE TABLE ingresos(
    codigo  int,
    stock_ingresado int)
INSERT INTO ingresos VALUES(1, 100),(1, 200)

CREATE TABLE ventas(
    codigo  int,
    stock_vendido int)
INSERT INTO ventas VALUES(1, 150),(1, 250)

SELECT p.codigo, i.stock_ingresado, v.stock_vendido
FROM productos      AS p
INNER JOIN ingresos AS i ON p.codigo=i.codigo
INNER JOIN ventas   AS v ON p.codigo=v.codigo;
```

Para prevenir este error, es necesario agrupar los datos antes de unirlos a la tabla productos. Esto se puede hacer con subconsultas, pero prefiero hacerlo con CTEs.

```
WITH cteIngresos AS(
    SELECT codigo,
            SUM(stock_ingresado) AS stock_ingresado
    FROM ingresos
    GROUP BY codigo
),cteVentas AS(
    SELECT codigo,
            SUM(stock_vendido) AS stock_vendido
    FROM ventas
    GROUP BY codigo
)
SELECT p.codigo, i.stock_ingresado, v.stock_vendido
FROM productos      AS p
INNER JOIN cteIngresos AS i ON p.codigo=i.codigo
INNER JOIN cteVentas   AS v ON p.codigo=v.codigo;
```